# What UIKeyboardNotification will be posted when the FirstResponse changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I want to receive UIKeyboard Notification when the FirstResponder changed(both UITextField) as to do some coding to prevent the UIKeyboard from covering my UITextField.But no UIKeyboard Notification was posted when the size of Keyboard did not change(I've tried to receive these notifications: `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`).I've received several UIKeyboard Notification when the size of Keyboard changed.Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

1. No `UIKeyboardNotification` will be posted when the `FirstResponse` changes.
2. `UIKeyboardNotification` will be posted with the `UIKeyboardFrame` when the size of keyboard changes.

This is a simple solution: store the `UIKeyboardFrame` in a property, then send your `scrollContentView` message (implement by yourself) when the `FirstResponse` changes and `UIKeyboard` was shown.